# ArcGIS Export to PDF data not editable

Tags: arcgis-desktop, export, pdf, arcgis-10.5

I have issue while exporting PDF, when i export PDF including Parcel layer its working fine but when add other layers in same file its not editable on PDF editor.
1-Pic: editable PDF with parcel layer
2-Pic : PDF along with other layers is not editable
[image: editable PDF with parcel layer]

[image: PDF along with other layers is not editable]

Answer (score 2):

a couple thoughts:

1. Do you have "export PDF layers only" or "export PDF layers and feature attributes" turned on on the advanced tab of the export dialog?
2. I've run into issues with exporting to vector files when I had transparency turned on in one of my layers--if any active layer has any degree of transparency, the exported pdf will probably be raster only. hard to tell from your screenshots if that's the case.

good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Thank You for your response, i already find solution. this problem happens due to some 
 complicated object in one of my layer (see attachment).

1. i turn off all layers and then turn on one by one.
2. every time when i turn On layer i export as PDF, until i find it
   export as raster.
3. then same above steps i repeat with layer's symbology.

at the end i detect my issue.

[image]